# How to force my ASP.net 2.0 app to recompile

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a ASP.net 2.0 app and I have made some changes the the source file ( cs files ). I uploaded the changes with the belief that it would auto-recompile. I also have the compiled dll in MY_APP/bin. I checked it and noticed that it did not recompile. Please understand I am new to this.

Comment: This is on the development webserver for this project I don't want to compile it locally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my #1 way to do this, add white space to the top of the web config file, after the xml declaration tag.

It forces the node to re-cache and recompile. We even have a page deep in the admin called Flush.aspx that does it for us.

Answer (score 4):

I use a similar method to ChanChan, but instead of whitespace I put a comment in the web.config to indicate when/why the config was edited.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to just actually run a build after making .cs changes.

Where are you running it? Is this for debugging or production?

Answer (score 0):

In VS menu you have Build -> Rebuild Solution