# Triggering recompilation of an ASP.NET website when the contents of a ~/plugin directory change (analog to ~/bin)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have a plugin directory in my (MVC4-)website root and want IIS to handle that directory the same way as it handles the ~/bin directory: a change should immediately trigger recompilation. Is this possible through web.config or any other method?

I'm trying to avoid workarounds with clever batch files touching the web.config to trigger a reload or anything like that.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330390/restart-asp-net-application-when-folder-contents-change

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force my ASP.net 2.0 app to recompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870/how-to-force-my-asp-net-2-0-app-to-recompile)

Comment: Both links don't answer my question. My plugin directory is not within my ~/bin folder and editing the web.config manually or some hack like that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Another suggestion in the first link is to detect any changes myself and  use `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` when appropriate. Feels hacky as well and requires Full Trust. Ultimately I'm just looking for a way to tell IIS: "Please consider changes to this folder/file as well when you decide when to recompile (and while you're at it, please shadowcopy those plugin DLLs as well)".

Comment: Marcel, I think this is going to be tricky.  The compiler trigger functionality is somewhat internal.  Nearest you're probably going to get without significant hacking is the compilation/codeSubDirectories attribute in web.config.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dwfbb7

Comment: Unfortunately codeSubDirectories are only allowed within the App_Code folder. I'm suprised that something like this is that tricky to do. Oh well, back to my "restart.bat" then.